# J48 output in terms of percentage

Tags: data-mining, classification, weka

I have a question related with the output of J48 in Weka.

I have a set of rules as output of my model. Id like to know if is possible to get a set of rules with percentage. For example, I have the follow set of rules as part of the output of my model:

```
A <= 0
|   B <= 2.5: 0 (19.0)
|   B > 2.5
|   |   C <= 7
|   |   |   D <= 14: 1 (5.0/1.0)
|   |   |   D > 14: 0 (3.0)
|   |   C > 7: 0 (3.0)
A > 0
|   A <= 3: 1 (7.0)
|   A > 3: 0 (2.0)
```

Thus, Id like to know some way to get one output like the follow:

```
IF A <= 0 AND B > 2.5 AND C <= 7 AND D <= 14 THEN X% chance to be TRUE
IF A > 0 AND A <= 3 THEN Y% chance to be TRUE
```

Is it possible to configure the J48's output to do something like that?

Anyone could help me?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't configure this with Weka's J48 implementation. You would have to implement the code to do that yourself, either by changing how the output is printed or by taking those ASCII trees and converting them to the rules you prefer.